# Laravel cashier package error

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use laravel cashier for a website I'm building but I am getting this error:

> RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45: No
>   supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Comment: You are missing an `APP_KEY` in your `.env` file.

Comment: @mohamed @Ohgodwhy Use the `php artisan key:generate` command to generate a random new key.

Comment: nothing changes ,the same error @JhonnyWalker